# How do I change the number of columns in a JTable using NetBeans 7.4 GUI designer?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, netbeans-7

I've created a JTable object using NetBeans 7.4.  By default it has four columns.  I only need two.  There is a columnCount property, but it is greyed out, so I can't change it.  How do I set my column count to two?

Comment: That's a work for `TableModel` look for that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within the properties of the JTable you can access a menu which is called "Model". There you will get inside an editor, where you can edit the appearance of your JTable.

[image]